# Parsing array in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I want to "split" an array (in Bash) to a sub-array while retaining all the array-like properties. Apparently, what I have tried has reduced the array to a string.

myscript.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
A=('foo' 'bar' 'bat' 'baz')
B=${A[@]:0:2} # Get first half of array

for i in ${!B[@]}; do
  echo "B[$i]: ${B[$i]}" # result: B[0]: foo bar
done
```

The result of this code is:

```
B[0]: foo bar
```

But the result I seek is:

```
B[0]: foo
B[1]: bar
```

What can I do to retain the array properties in `B` that will allow me to properly loop thru its elements?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/278642/13792

Comment: Crossposting: http://superuser.com/q/1069015/340330

Comment: Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)

Comment: You forgot the brackets: `B=("${A[@]:0:2}")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
A=('foo 123' 'bar 123' 'bat 123' 'baz 123')
B=("${A[@]:0:2}")
declare -p B
```

Output:

```
declare -a B='([0]="foo 123" [1]="bar 123")'
```